# PL/SQL PLS-00208: identifier 'TYPE' is not a legal cursor attribute

Tags: oracle, plsql

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to write a procedure that creates a table using [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011).

**What is the problem**

I get the following error while compiling the procedure:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/5      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
4/80     PLS-00208: identifier 'TYPE' is not a legal cursor attribute
```

**Procedure:**

```
create or replace procedure createTab is

    begin
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table thisYearCustomerNames (id ' || customer.id%type || ', name ' ||
                                                               customer.name%type || ', points ' ||
                                                               customer.points%type || ')';
    end;
    /
```

**Customer Table**

```
Name               Null?      Type
 -----------------------------------------
 ID                NOT NULL   NUMBER(5)
 NAME                         VARCHAR2(30)
 ADDRESS                      VARCHAR2(40)
 POINTS            NOT NULL   NUMBER(10)
 DATE_OF_JOINING              DATE
 GENDER                       CHAR(1)
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL is hard to write because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors. I suggest you start by writing static SQL and make sure you have a valid statement which runs in SQL Developer (or whatever you use). Once you've done that you can convert it into dynamic code.

Comment: I use notepad++ for code and run it in sql terminal as a file using `@` operator. Is it a good way ?? and thanks for you precious suggestion really appreciated. thanks again for taking time to produce such a nice suggest. will try it.

Comment: I think it's the best way for a beginner. The more SQL you write by hand the more you will learn. Too many people start with IDEs which give them the illusion of productivity at the expense of understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to create a table with `%type` attributes , which is not permitted.

`%TYPE` attributes are only allowed as PL/SQL variables and cannot be used while creating a table.

As per Oracle documentation, [%TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/type_attribute.htm#LNPLS01352):

> The %TYPE attribute lets you declare a constant, variable, collection
>   element, record field, or subprogram parameter to be of the same data
>   type as a previously declared variable or column

So, if you need to create a table with the same definition as that of `Customer`, without data, use a `Create table as select *` with 0 rows.

I.e.,

```
create table thisYearCustomerNames AS SELECT id,name,points FROM customer where ROWNUM < 1;
```

And you are trying to place column names outside `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` such as `...id ' || customer.id%type` - which too would not have worked. This is the appropriate way.

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table thisYearCustomerNames AS SELECT id,name,points
    FROM customer where ROWNUM < 1';
END;
```

Comment: Just to add, `%type` is not a tag that is expanded at runtime. It is an instruction to the PL/SQL compiler.